# I'm trying to run mdpnp openice on rpi (RTI DDS)

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi, data-distribution-service

I'm getting this error. MdPnP project provides a java demo-app. I have it already running on beaglebone black and works fine. I´m trying to run it on RPi and I encounter this problem.

Application hangs when it tries to use dds external library.

```
Rpi uname -a = Linux raspberrypi 3.12.26-rt40+ #1 PREEMPT RT Fri Sep 19 23:59:27 MSK 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Please advise.
Thanks,

> A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
>
> SIGILL (0x4) at pc=0xa8003d48, pid=4183, tid=3058177136
>
> JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_60-b19) (build 1.7.0_60- b19)
>   Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (24.60-b09 mixed mode linux-arm )
>   Problematic frame:
>
> C  [libnddscore.so+0x72d48]  call_gmon_start+0x7

Comment: hmmm did you try to run any other rti programs on your computer? maybe it doesnt like your c compiler. you should try their simplehello program. Also RTI has a great forum to use as well when you encounter RTI specific problems. that is a file from rti is is having trouble with

Comment: also was there a core dump at all, if it is openjdk i may know the answer...